# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The database is already in use by another process: org.hsqldb.persist.NIOLockFile

Tags: mysql, sqoop, oozie

I have replaced sqoop metatsore with a MySQL db.

When I try to run a saved sqoop job from the command line, it "asks" me for the password and run the job when I supply it.

However, I need to run this job through oozie.

--password is not recognized as a valid argument here in command line while executing sqoop saved job and anyway, it keeps asking for password through the prompt.

Now, when I try to run it through oozie,

I get

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The database is already in use by 

another process: org.hsqldb.persist.NIOLockFile@950abfc6[file 

=/home/yarn/.sqoop/metastore.db.lck, exists=false, locked=false, 

 valid=false, fl =null]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 

/home/yarn/.sqoop/metastore.db.lck (No such file or directory)
```

What is this and why is this? I am directly connecting to my MySQL metatsore and have configured sqoop-site.xml accordingly.

Why is this trying to to connect to hsqldb?

Why is it locked?

How do I fix this?

Also, how do I supply password for execution of sqoop job in oozie?